# Bucle infinito al iterar array

Tags: javascript

Resulta que ejecuto este código en el Dev Tools de Chrome

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var newStr = str.split(" ");
 //TeSt 10 array newStr
 console.log(newStr);
 for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
  // TeSt 20 1era letra de cada palabra
  newStr.push(newStr[i][0].toUpperCase())
  
  }
  console.log(newStr)
}

titleCase("I´m a little tea pot");
```

Pues acto seguido me salta: *debugging connection was closed. Reason: Render process gone*

Que por lo que leído es que hay un bucle infinito. Sin embargo mi unico bucle tiene final, cuando alcance el valor de newStr.length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es infinito porque haces un push al mismo array en cada iteración

Si tienes 5 elementos en el array, y al entrar en el primero añades 1, tienes 6 elementos. Cuando entres al 2ndo tendrás 7 elementos, cuando entres al 3ero, tendrás 8 elementos... y así infinitamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionarlo, haz `push` a un array temporal:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var newStr = str.split(" ");
  var tempArr = [];
  //TeSt 10 array newStr
  console.log("Original" , newStr);
  for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    // TeSt 20 1era letra de cada palabra
    tempArr.push(newStr[i][0].toUpperCase())

  }
  console.log("Mayúsculas", tempArr)
}

titleCase("I´m a little tea pot");
```

Sin embargo, te estaría haciendo un array de Mayusculas, no de palabras empezando en mayúsculas.

Para ello, puedes concatenarlo con `tempArr.push(newStr[i][0].toUpperCase() + newStr[i].substring(1))`

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var newStr = str.split(" ");
  var tempArr = [];
  //TeSt 10 array newStr
  console.log("Original" , newStr);
  for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    // TeSt 20 1era letra de cada palabra
    tempArr.push(newStr[i][0].toUpperCase() + newStr[i].substring(1))
  }
  console.log("Mayúsculas", tempArr)
}

titleCase("I´m a little tea pot");
```